# Calling an Array within a program (java)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently putting together a basic world viewer program. At each viewpoint, I have 4 pictures, each at 90 degrees to one another. I have created an array of photos for each viewpoint and an String currentPoint which will hold the name of the viewpoint. I think there is a way to take the name of the current array and call the contents of it so I need only write one set of code for the turn left ad turn right functions below, but I can't think what it would be. How is it done?

Comment: I don't really know if I understand completely but could you put the arrays in a map with the String as the keys?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your array `array` is arranged in the order [north-facing, east-facing, south-facing, west-facing], and that you have an index `i` indicating the index of the current view (0 for north, 1 for east, 2 for south, 3 for west). Then to "turn left" is to decrement `i` modulo 4 and to "turn right" is to increment `i` modulo 4.

With this approach, turning right is straightforward: `i = (i + 1) % 4`.

Turning left is a little bit tricker, because `%` is actually defined as a remainder operator in Java, rather than as a modulus operator, so `i = (i - 1) % 4` will not work (it will leave `i == -1` when it should be `i == 3`). Instead, you can write: `i = (i + 3) % 4`.

(With this in mind, we can define a full set of absolute directional constants — `NORTH` as 0, `EAST` as 1, `SOUTH` as 2, `WEST` as 3 — and relative directional constants — `FRONT` as 0, `RIGHT` as 1, `BACK` as 2, `LEFT` as 3. Then, for example, `WEST == (NORTH + LEFT) % 4` and `NORTH == (WEST + RIGHT) % 4`.)